# Question about exercise 17.16 in TeXbook

Tags: math-mode, boxes, box

The answer to the exercise is:

```
\def\sqr#1#2{{\vcenter{\vbox{
  \hrule height.#2pt
  \hbox{\vrule width.#2pt height#1pt \kern#1pt \vrule width.#2pt}
  \hrule height.#2pt}}}}
\def\square{\mathchoice\sqr34\sqr34\sqr{2.1}3\sqr{1.5}3}
```

I wonder why extra `\vbox` is used. May its absence influence the outcome in any way?

Comment: please note my updated answer (my first answer was wrong)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `\vcenter` is handled as a `\vbox` except that a `vcent` atom is wrapped around the construct which finally means that the resulting box is adjusted so its height+depth are centred on the math axis. However as Udo pointed out in comments the finer points of appendix G in the TeXBook do mean that there are some differences in the way `\scriptspace` is handled.

[image]

```
\scriptspace=5pt % excessive ammount to make things clearer

\def\sqr#1#2{{\vcenter{\vbox{
  \hrule height.#2pt
  \hbox{\vrule width.#2pt height#1pt \kern#1pt \vrule width.#2pt}
  \hrule height.#2pt}}}}
\def\square{\mathchoice\sqr34\sqr34\sqr{2.1}3\sqr{1.5}3}


\def\sqrb#1#2{{\vcenter{
  \hrule height.#2pt
  \hbox{\vrule width.#2pt height#1pt \kern#1pt \vrule width.#2pt}
  \hrule height.#2pt}}}
\def\squareb{\mathchoice\sqrb34\sqrb34\sqrb{2.1}3\sqrb{1.5}3}


$|A_{ \square}|\, |A_{\squareb }|$

\bye
```

Udo highlights the relevant rules in appendix G as follows:

> It is the nature of the `\hrule` which extends to the width of the
>   enclosing box.
>
> And here it is the width of the hbox plus `\scriptspace`. With the
>   `\vbox` the width of the `\hrule` has just the width of the `\hbox`;
>   `\scriptspace` is applied later.
>
> (Appendix G: Rule 1 jumps over the hrule, the postprocessing in rule
>   18 applies the `\scriptspace` to the hbox or the vbox.)

In particular it is 18b, quoting from the TeXBook:

> 18b. If the superscript field is empty (so that there is a subscript
>   only), set box *x* to the subscript in style C↓, and add
>   `\scriptspace` to *w(x)*

Which means with only one box, the horizontal rules extend, but with nested boxes (of any type) the width of the inner list is unchanged.

Comment: Your answer is correct for D and T styles. But look at the use case of the
macro `\sqr` and observe that the `\hrule`s have no width, i.e., it is *. So
in $$A_{\square}$$ the `\scriptspace` is applied and destroys the square box
if `\vbox{` and one `}` are deleted.

Comment: @UdoWermuth I can't delete an accepted answer, but if you post a right answer I'll get the OP to unaccept this and I'll delete, thanks.

Comment: @UdoWermuth I can confirm you are right but just at the moment I don't see where  the texbook statement that vcenter is treated as vbox lead me astray, I'll need to stare at appendix g again....

Comment: It is the nature of the `\hrule` which extends to the width of the
enclosing box. And here it is the width of the hbox plus
`\scriptspace`. With the `\vbox` the width of the `\hrule` has just
the width of the `\hbox`; `\scriptspace` is applied later. Please,
don't delete your answer, edit it.
(Appendix G: Rule 1 jumps over the hrule, the postprocessing in rule
18 applies the `\scriptspace` to the hbox or the vbox.)

Comment: @UdoWermuth done thanks:-)